# How can I affix a loose thermostat to the wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat, heater

I have a digital thermostat that is Luxpro. It appears to be not as strongly attached to the wall recently and for that reason I have to push it against the wall to turn on at times.

The thermostat itself is working otherwise. Does this need repair or replacement? Sometimes it takes two or three attempts to turn on the heaters.

Who should I call to fix it? I live in Seattle and weekends are preferable.

They came and changed the thermostat to a Honeywell. Picture attached. Any thoughts? I was charged 521 for diagnosis and labor

[image]

Comment: Specific contractor recommendations are off-topic here.  Have you considered simply replacing the thermostat though?

Comment: Can you post some pictures, I do not understand why it has to be pushed against the wall. Also can you attach it properly so it does not move around?

Comment: Try replacing the batteries first...then check for loose wire connections (make sure the screws holding the wires are tight)....then replace it with a Honeywell.

Comment: If it is loose on the wall, you should be able to wiggle it with your hand.  If so then it is a simple fix to remount it to the wall.  If tight to the wall then follow @SteveWellens comment.

Comment: Probably loose on the backing plate, and just needs to be snapped back on properly, unless some abuse has caused the backing plate to be ripped loose of the wall. And this is not a place to find someone to come to your house on the weekend to fix it.

Comment: The mounting plate may have been attached to drywall with just screws and no anchors and the drywall is crumbling letting the whole thing move. Or, cheap drywall anchors may have been used and/or installed improperly and they're now coming loose. Give us a picture of the thermostat, then see if you can figure out how to remove it from the mounting plate and give us a pic of that, too. If you can't figure out how to remove it, several clear, focused pics of the thermostat may allow us to figure out how to get it off so you can investigate behind it.

Comment: If you're not up for fixing it yourself, ask a neighbor for a recommendation of a handyman to come fix the mount on the wall for you.

Comment: I agree with Steve batteries first but if not the fix it’s probably a loose connection, simple DIY no contractor or handyman needed.

Comment: I added two pictures. One is the side of the Luxpro thermostat where is attached to the wall. You can see tha gap. The other shows that the temp is set for 67 whereas the room is holding at 63 when I woke up in the morning. I had to push the thermostat in order for it to function again in the morning.

Comment: It’s absolutely not turning on the heater now. The other thermostat is working on the right side of the house. Could it be a boiler issue?

Answer (score 3):

The possible causes of your problem can be grouped by likelihood into three categories.

**MOST LIKELY**

**Loose Wire.** As @Steve Wellens indicated, a wire is not securely attached and operating intermittently.

**Mode Misunderstanding.** I often see people who assume they are in Hold mode when they are in Program mode.

Programmable thermostats have two primary running modes: Program and Hold. Program mode bases target temperature on a user programmable schedule and is typically invoked through some variation of “Run”, “Run Schedule”, etc. Hold mode overrides Program mode for manually setting target temperature. Most Hold modes are permanent, some are temporary and usually indicated by “Temporary Hold” in the display.

I see the “Hold” indicator on the thermostat but I don’t know if Hold mode was engaged when you went to sleep.

**MODERATELY LIKELY**

**Bad thermostat.** Intermittent thermostat problems are relatively rare, when a thermostat doesn’t work, it usually never works. However, it happens.

**LEAST LIKELY**

**Weak batteries.** If weak, your display probably wouldn't work and/or a low battery indicator would come on.

**Weak mount.** Though a poorly mounted thermostat will absorb some button pressing forces, I doubt it caused you to wake up to 63 degrees when your target was 67. That being said, your thermostat SHOULD be mounted solidly.

**CONCLUSION**

If you want to take your thermostat apart and troubleshoot yourself, or have a friend that can do so, please say so, and we can take it one step at a time. If you want to hire someone to solve the problem, a competent handyman or HVAC company can probably solve this.

Comment: Good answer, but cost is off topic here, particularly because it varies so much between region. I suggest removing that portion.

Comment: The thermostat appears 100% disconnected today. It is looking functional by itself but it absolutely does not turn on the heaters. I have another thermostat on the right side of the house that is turning on the right side of the houses heaters. Could it be the boiler or is it a thermostat issue?

Comment: I attached a picture of a thermostat that they exchanged it with. It’s a Honeywell. Any thoughts?  I was charged 521 $

Comment: Is the new thermostat operating correctly? Is it solidly mounted to the wall?

Comment: They attached the new thermostat today. So far so good. The reviews on Amazon are just fine.  It is solidly mounted. My only concern is that the plus minus signs are going to be wiped off as they are just ink. Does that make sense?  Here is the model Honeywell th4110u2005/u